# XML tag replace

Tags: xml, dom, domparser, xmlelement

I need to replace `<title>` with `<sec-title>` in the below XML code. but the result removed `<named-content>` tag from `<title>`.

```
    var parser, xmlDoc;
    var text = "<bookstore><book>" +
        "<title>Teting<named-content content-type='index'></named-content></title>" +
        "<author>Giada De Laurentiis<named-content content-type='index'></named-content></author>" +
        "<year>2005</year>" +
        "</book></bookstore>";

    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");

    var t = xmlDoc.querySelector('title');
    var newElement = xmlDoc.createElement('sec-title');
    var t_clone = t.cloneNode(true);
    var t_content = t_clone.childNodes[0];
    newElement.appendChild(t_content);

    t.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, t);
    t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
```

Result of the above code:
[image]

`<title>` get replaced but `<named-content>` tag disappeared.

I need: 
`<sec-title>Testing<named-content content-type='index'></named-content></sec-title>`